# Single Page Application Architecture

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I am trying to write a basic SPA and lots of libraries out there. I looked at backbone, angularjs2, flux, redux, reactjs but I really want something simple and I want to really understand what each piece of code does. So these libraries are too cumbersome for me now.

My application will be run as desktop application (with electron) not on an actual web browser. What I really want to understand is how to handle model changes and view actions.

The application uses localforage for its persistence database.

I have an AppComponent (we can say  it is the master component of the system) that any other components are child in it.

AppComponent has responsibility to listen all socket events for entire system, and has a dependency for a pubsub mechanism.

**(this is just example not even test code. names are dummy for being understandable)**

```
class AppComponent {

  init(){

    socket.on("delete::book", function(bookid){
        bookService.removeBookFromDatabase(bookid);
        pubSub.emit("delete::book", bookid);
    })  

    socket.on("add::book", function(book){
        bookService.addBookToDatabase(book).then(function(){
            pubSub.emit("add::book", book);
        }).catch(function(err){
            pubSub.emit("add::book", err);
        });

    })  

    pubSub.on("add::book", function(book){
      socket.emit("add::book", book);
    });


  }

  render(){
    return "Layout";
  }

  destroy(){

  }

}
```

---

```
class BookshelfComponent {

  constructor(books){
    this.books = books;
  }

  init(){
    var that = this;

    pubSub.on("delete::book", function(bookid){
      that.books.remove(bookid);
      that.render();
    });

    $("#btnAddBook").on("click", function(){
      pubSub.emit("add::book", { id : 1, name : "Test Book"});
    });  

  }

  render(){
    //render with this.books
    return "Layout";
  }

  destroy(){
     pubSub.off();
  }  
}
```

So the logic is AppContainer listens all events and makes database operations if needed and then emitting events to other components to use.

**First of all is there anything wrong on this logic? Can you give me any advice?**

If this is ok, what **Models** responsibility on this system? Just for dummy objects or should do more ?

Comment: angularjs2 is definitely too difficult, I tried it and abandoned it. React.js however, is the best I've come across. It's been less than 1 month since I've started learning react and I've almost finished a website with it. Seriously, you should learn a framework instead.

Comment: Look like you have endless loop - on click you are call for `pubSub.emit` then you intercept this event and call for `socket.emit`, and after it works you are emit `pubSub.emit` with same book?

Comment: And yes, I like when model is a dummy object. Better do wrappers such as `function Book(book){this.name = book.name}` to make it more readable and prevent mixins magic.

Comment: @degr I write the code while asking the question (: The code doesnt any purpose expect trying to tell the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to answer your question, because there is no question, but I will do it. As usual SPA contain this modules:

1. Data fetching module, that will get data from server
2. Data module that will store all incoming data. It can be same as data fetching, but I dislike this approach.
3. Components module that will display this your data.

As usual peoples create some additional abstraction layers in data fetching module, so it contain two or more layers - one for data fetching, another one for data processing and application buisness logic. Also this module should be responsible for 'post' operations. After post operation, better update Data layer instead of view. Also you should think about authentification, but this is other topic.

No need to try make Data module `smart`, because it is impossible to make it 100% sync with database. I like subPub approach, so better emit event, when your Data layer will recieve some updates. Your active components should be subscribed to data layer, so you will be able to update view. As usual this layer contain pack of 'Stores'. Each Store is class than contain some fetched data, as usual one store for one type of database entity (or entity view). Also, store can contain application logic data. But from my opinion, application logic data should be incapsulated inside of `view` components (react flux developers have other opinion).

Among all components you should have top-level component that will be responsible about application routes. If you are talking about web application, it should resolve URL and pass some parameters to application `pages`. `Page` component should be a class that will receive only small count of input params for it instantiation, for an example:

```
/books/12
```

Your class BookForm should receive 12. Of course your book form should be binded to URL with this template: '/books/:id'.

View components should be simple, but should be easy to instantiation. It's difficult to reuse them if you have 20 constructor arguments.

Ask questions, if you are still have them.

So, when your client open page, your application should check - is it authentificated (or is user have access to page), if yes, display page, if not, redirect to login and better save URL to return user back after login. All other interactions inside of your application should be done by router. You should fire event to notify router about page changing, and router should display page. From my opinion better do it using `history.pushState` and `onchange URL` event (I forgot name of it). Each well known framework already contain basic components, so, better choose something, and do not write it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by exactly while you say Data layer ?

Comment: I add some more info

Comment: So you mean stores (for example BookStore, UserStore, etc...) can listen events for what their interests from the server, does what they need (save it to db for example) and emit messages to related components ? Then store means some kind of data layer (with or without business logic) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. From my experience, store should not contain business logic.   Actually, with this architecture should be used event channel, not pubSub.

Comment: So 7 years later people start to realize that putting business logic to data layer is a bad idea.